# Reading from UART RxD of the Raspberry Pi in Assembly

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, uart

I have a Pi connected to my laptop through the serial port (UART). I wrote the function ReadChar which reads a char as input on the UART's RXD port but it doesn't work. When running, the program is stuck in the ReadChar infinite loop waiting for some data even when I write something in the console. The function WriteChar works perfectly fine so I think that the issue could be either in the function ReadChar or in the initialisation of the UART.

Who can help me with this?

Thanks a lot.

**The main function:**

```
main:
BL InitializeUART
BL ReadChar
BL WriteChar @ this function works properly</code>
```

**The ReadChar function:**

```
ReadChar:
LDR R0, =AUX_MU_LSR_REG
LDR R1, [R0]
TST R1, #1
BEQ ReadChar
LDR R0, =AUX_MU_IO_REG
LDR R1, [R0]        
MOV pc, lr
```

**Initialisation of the UART**

```
.equ AUX_ENABLES,   0x20215004
.equ AUX_MU_IER_REG,    0x20215044
.equ AUX_MU_CNTL_REG,   0x20215060
.equ AUX_MU_LCR_REG,    0x2021504C
.equ AUX_MU_MCR_REG,    0x20215050
.equ AUX_MU_IIR_REG,    0x20215048
.equ AUX_MU_BAUD_REG,   0x20215068
.equ GPPUD,    0x20200094
.equ GPPUDCLK0,    0x20200098
.equ GPCLR0,    0x20200028
.equ GPFSEL1,    0x20200004



InitializeUART:
PUSH {lr}
@ Enable UART
MOV R1, #1
LDR R0, =AUX_ENABLES
STR R1, [R0]
@ disable interrupts
MOV R1, #0
LDR R0, =AUX_MU_IER_REG
STR R1, [R0]
@ disable transmit/receive
MOV R1, #0
LDR R0, =AUX_MU_CNTL_REG
STR R1, [R0]
@ set 8 bits communication
MOV R1, #3
LDR R0, =AUX_MU_LCR_REG
STR R1, [R0]
@ set the RTS line high
MOV R1, #0
LDR R0, =AUX_MU_MCR_REG
STR R1, [R0]
@ leave disable interrupts
MOV R3, #0
LDR R0, =AUX_MU_IER_REG
STR R3, [R0]
@ clear the input and output buffers
MOV R1, #198
LDR R0, =AUX_MU_IIR_REG
STR R1, [R0]
@ set BAUD = 270
MOV R1, #200
ADD R1, R1, #70
LDR R0, =AUX_MU_BAUD_REG
STR R1, [R0]
@ Set GPIO line 14 for transmission (TXD)
LDR R0, =GPFSEL1
LDR R1, [R0]
BIC R3, R1, #28672
ORR R3, R3, #8192
STR R3, [R0]
@ Set GPIO line 15 for receiving (RXD)
LDR R1, [R0]
BIC R3, R1, #229376
ORR R3, R3, #65536
STR R3, [R0]
@ disable GPIO pull-up/down
MOV R1, #0
LDR R0, =GPPUD
STR R1, [R0]
@ wait for 150 cycles
MOV R1, #0
cycle1: ADD R1, R1, #1
BL Cycle
CMP R1, #150
BNE cycle1
@ Assert clock lines (14 & 15)
MOV R1, #16384  @ 1<<14
LDR R0, =GPPUDCLK0
STR R1, [R0]
MOV R1, #32768 @ 1<<15
STR R1, [R0]
@ wait for 150 cycles
MOV R1, #0
cycle2: ADD R1, R1, #1
BL Cycle
CMP R1, #150
BNE cycle2
@ clear clock lines
MOV R1, #0
LDR R0, =GPCLR0
STR R1, [R0]
@ enable bits 0 and 1 in CONTROL
MOV R1, #2
LDR R0, =AUX_MU_CNTL_REG
STR R1, [R0]
@ return
POP {pc}        

Cycle:      MOV pc, lr
```

Comment: Do you have a serial receive interrupt enabled which might be claiming the data first?  Are you indeed running bare-metal with no OS?  Have you validated the electrical connections with other software, say when booted to linux?  Of course an overlooked configuration issue is a likely suspect too.  Is there a working example out there somewhere?

Comment: Yes it is running bare-metal with no OS. The function WriteChar takes a ASCII char in R1 as argument. For instance, `MOV R1, #'A'  BL WriteChar` will print the letter A in the virtual console.

Comment: The fact that writing works implies relatively little about if reading will - on some devices, not even that the baudrate is correct (usually it is the same divider, but not always).  So most of the ideas I raised still need checking.

Comment: If rx interrupts are enabled there must be an interrupt routime. Otherwise the processor executes random code and may not return from the interrupt at all. If there is, it probably reads the characters before there is a chance for polling.

Comment: Interrupts are disabled. The comment was incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In the last step of the initialization, only the transmitter is enabled and not the receiver. So #3 (0b11) should be stored instead of #2 (0b10).

```
@ enable bits 0 and 1 in CONTROL
MOV R1, #3
LDR R0, =AUX_MU_CNTL_REG
STR R1, [R0]
```